# SpringMVC error: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute

Tags: spring-mvc

Environment: SpringMVC Maven Netbeans Glassfish

> SEVERE: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.(BindStatus.java:141)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:178)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:198)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:164)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:151)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:142)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:126)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:421)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:142)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
>       at org.apache.jsp.user_jsp._jspx_meth_form_input_0(user_jsp.java:178)
>       at org.apache.jsp.user_jsp._jspx_meth_form_form_0(user_jsp.java:120)
>       at org.apache.jsp.user_jsp._jspService(user_jsp.java:76)
>       at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:403)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:492)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

user.jsp:

```
    <form:form action="createuser.do" modelAttribute="user" method="POST">
        <table align="center" >
            <tr>
                <td>User Name :</td>
                <td><form:input path="userName"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>  
                <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
```

My controller:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/createuser.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void create(@ModelAttribute("user")  User user, BindingResult result) {
        System.out.print("user name: "+user.getUserName());
    }
}
```

I got this error on browser when I access "http://localhost:8080/NBGFMN/user.jsp"
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute

If I remove `form:input path="userName"`) from jsp, the jsp displays correctly, when I click submit button console outputs "user name: null".

There are so many posts in stackoverflow about this same error, but none of the solution works for me.

I added the following GET method and welcome.jsp

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/welcome.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView printHello()
{
    ModelAndView m = new ModelAndView("welcome");
    m.addObject("ppp", "hello");
    return m;
}

<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <c:out value="${ppp}" ></c:out>
    </body>
</html>
```

And access "http://localhost:8080/NBGFMN/welcome.do" It works perfectly.

I add the following GET (to create a user), it works:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/createuser.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String create(ModelMap mm) 
{
    mm.addAttribute("auser", new User("Andy"));
    return "welcome";
}

<body>
    <c:out value="${auser.userName}" ></c:out>
</body>
```

I access "http://localhost:8080/NBGFMN/createuser.do", the browser outputs "Andy"

But the form POST is still not working.

Comment: Could you add the `GET`handler? Are you adding a model attribute there or via a `@ModelAttribute("user")` annotated method?

Comment: Hi, I added the following GET method and welcome.jsp, it works perfectly. As for @ModelAttribute("user"), yes I had it. I google this error message online and see all people said about it, but it doesn't work for me. I've try SpringMVC-3.0.7 and latest 3.1.2, still not working

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set a request attribute in the `GET` handler with name `user` and value some object that includes field `userName`? Like this:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/createuser.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void create(ModelMap mm) {
        mm.addAttribute("user", new UserFormObject());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/createuser.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void create(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult result) {
        System.out.print("user name: "+user.getUserName());
    }
}
```

In your JSP you need to specify `method=post` for your `form:form` element, the [default method is `GET`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/Overview.html#form-submission-0), which doesn't match your handler.

Comment: I added the following GET method (to create a user), it works

Comment: Try specifying `method=post` in your `form:form` element, the default method is `GET`, which doesn't match your handler.

Comment: I am so sorry I actually have method="POST" in the form. I created so many test cases in the end I mess it up by the time I post it here. But it is still not working. Only if I remove form:input path="userName" that I can access user.jsp

Comment: Please try to add the GET handler for the specific page and add the user attribute (not for another page like welcome.do and not with a different attribute name like auser). Use that GET and the POST you are trying to do together.

Answer (score 0):

There are two important points I have to make in this context:

1. `BindingResult` is associated with the immediate `@ModelAttribute` entry
2. when you report error, you associate it with a model attribute. This attribute name should be present in the `@ModelAttribute`, and is case sensitive.

Sample:

```
@ModelAttribute("side") SideDetails s,BindingResult sideResult          
@ModelAttribute("track") TrackDetails t, BindingResult trackResult
```

In above example, `sideResult` will have target as `SideDetails`. Similarly, `trackResult` will have `TrackDetails` as target.

While reporting error with `sideResult`, the attribute name will be searched in model `SideDetails`. Failing to find this attribute, we get the error reported in this blog.

Hope this helps.